# how to stop a cron job - cpanel

Tags: php, perl, cron, cpanel

My cron job in my cpanel looks like this

```
cd public_html/Staging/ff; perl sendmail.pl >/dev/null
```

[image]

The sendmail.pl looks like this

```
my $php = `php decode.php`;
```

The decode.php looks like this

```
$user = "Hello";
$fh = fopen("output.txt","a+");
fwrite($fh,$user."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

`output.txt` file gets on updating every second, even though i've called it for 1 hour.

Now how do i stop this job based in PID?

Where should i find PID?

How do i find all cron jobs running right now? and stop it at once?

I wanted to call `sendmail.pl` every hour.

Comment: "I am using cpanel on windows machine" -- that doesn't even make sense. According to their [system requirements](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Installation%20Guide%20-%20System%20Requirements), cPanel only runs on Linux.

Comment: Thanks.  and yes i know thats nothing to do with cpanel. I am accessing my linux server through cpanel from wiindows machine.. I am unable to stop my cron job.. how do i do it?

Comment: `top` or `ps` to get the pid, and then `kill`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have * in minute it now runs every minute. Try putting a value there (for instance 0) to run it every hour on that minute number. And only have star in hour.